# Is there any method to detect slow (partially failed) kafka broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

I faced the following situation with kafka 2.3 cluster. One of the brokers had issues with disk and process all requests very slow. Kafka cluster didn't detect it as a failure and didn't remove it from cluster. This situation caused timeouts on our producers while they
were trying to send messages to partitions served by this unhealthy broker. I wonder, is there any tools which are able to detect such slow brokers and remove them from cluster? Or maybe new versions of kafka are able to detect such situation?

Comment: You could start with OS monitoring tooling like Prometheus node-exporter, DataDog, NewRelic, NetData, etc... Kafka doesn't monitor the OS failures, only cares that the JVM is active and it can access its log directories for topics